Bundling js and css with Vue and Webpack
I am trying to optimize a Vue (v3.2)+Webpack (v5.8) app, and I haven’t been properly introduced to Vue. I have tens of css and js references in my index.html. Those css'es and js'es are currently in folders public/A, public/B. There are jquery, and all sorts of other old-school (pre-ES6) libraries.
Currently they are under public/myLib and public/myLibModified and they are copied to dist/ on vue-cli-service build.
What would be proper or better place for them (i.e source files)?
Is it possible to bundle (not sure if this is the right term) js and css them together with Webpack? Feeding them as file list (i.e NOT iterating over directories) is probably the only way since the order matters. Or do I need some other library (gulp/gulp-concat) or that? I'd prefer Webpack that's already in use.
If possible, then can it be done on the “main” build or do I need to run separate build for that?
How can I retain the non-modular js?

The question isn't specific enough. What does code in public/ look like, what exactly do you expect from build process? In the most simple scenario you could move all .js and .css to /src and import all of them in the order they are supposed to be loaded in index.js, and then use it as entry point for webpack build

@EstusFlask Edited my question

Generally it could be done the way I suggested. Just move to src (not assets, because they aren't images or something) and import 'some-script in app's entry point. You may have problems with non-modular code being bundled this way. You can only figure this out by trial and error and control in which order and moment they are loaded and executed. Otherwise something like gulp-concat and gulp-concat-css would be more blunt and less breaking. It may be not a big deal if you load them separately, make sure you serve them with http/2 to avoid performance penalty, do some tests if you have doubts

Ok, if I import 'some-script', how can I deal with non-modular code?

Import includes them as is and they may work as intended depending on what happens inside. E.g. ES module forces "use strict" e and makes global "this" undefined which a script could rely on
